# Neo4j - Pass Variable to apoc.cypher.runFile CALL

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a .cypher file that I want to run using jdbcOperations like this:

```
jdbcOperations.update("CALL apoc.cypher.runFile(\""+{CYPHER FILE HERE}+"\")");
```

**But**,

In that cypher file I have another CALL

```
CALL apoc.load.json({PATH TO JSON FILE HERE}) YIELD value AS item
```

I want that JSON File Path to be dynamic, to pass the path to it as a variable , but I have not succeed with any of my tries.

Help ?

Comment: I think it's just not possible ... a file is a static ressources, and it should be sufficient to execute its self. On queries, you can give parameters.  But stupid question, why are you doing this ? Why are you not executeing the query directly ?

Comment: @logisima That question wasn't stupid at all :) I was trying to add functionality for an existing module without a need to refactor a pieces of code, I have tried a lot of different approaches, without any success though.

Comment: @logisima Any best practices on executing a big Cypher via jdbcOperations? For an example if I will store it as a String.

Comment: There is nothing particular with a jdbcOperations ... so if you follow the good cypher practice, it will be enought. Can you give an example of a `Big Cypher` ?